# Error:(14, 33) java: cannot access org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to add spring boot support in uniCenta open source POS version 4.4.2. That version of uniCenta is maven based desktop application. I am getting **Error:(14, 33) java: cannot access org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable
class file for org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable not found** error. I added the following dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring</artifactId>  
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>  
      <version>2.0.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

<plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
```

If some want to view complete POM.xml file please click here https://github.com/MuzammalHussain6313/muzammal-ionic/blob/master/pom.xml

I also apply several changes (like scope of dependencies) in dependencies recommended from stackoverflow answers.

I still getting same error. What should I Do now? please help.

Comment: You are including _ancient_ versions _at random_. I have been doing Spring development professionally for over 10 years, and 2.5 was obsolete _when I started_. Use the Spring Boot parent, and then try not to provide _any_ versions (it takes care of the most common ones for you). Best of all, use https://start.spring.io to generate your project.

Comment: Your dependencies are a mess. Remove the `spring` and `spring-core` dependencies. Use the same version for the `spring-boot` dependencies and the `spring-amqp` version is ancient as well (use the Spring BOot starter for it instead).